# SVG read letters and number chracters C#

Tags: c#, svg, .net-core

I'm looking for a way to get letters and numbers from an SVG file. I can read the XML, that's no problem but the snippet below should be an 'H' (without quotes) but I'm not sure to parse that so that my code returns 'H' and its X/Y values.

**H**

```
<path d="M922.29 113.89L922.29 99.97 924.12 99.97 924.12 105.69 931.36 105.69 931.36 99.97 933.2 99.97 933.2 113.89 931.36 113.89 931.36 107.33 924.12 107.33 924.12 113.89 922.29 113.89Z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="black"/>
```

**U**

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M945.39 99.97L947.23 99.97 947.23 108.01 947.23 109.06 946.99 110.72 946.76 111.34 946.52 111.96 945.66 112.96 945.04 113.35 944.42 113.74 942.8 114.12 941.79 114.12 940.82 114.12 939.22 113.79 938.6 113.45 937.97 113.11 937.09 112.14 936.82 111.5 936.56 110.86 936.29 109.11 936.29 108.01 936.29 99.97 938.13 99.97 938.13 108 938.13 108.91 938.3 110.25 938.46 110.68 938.63 111.11 939.21 111.77 939.62 112 940.03 112.23 941.04 112.47 941.63 112.47 942.65 112.47 944.1 112.01 944.53 111.54 944.96 111.08 945.39 109.31 945.39 108 945.39 99.97Z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="black"/>
```

**2**

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M339.08 213.69L339.08 214.93 332.19 214.93 332.18 214.7 332.26 214.25 332.34 214.04 332.47 213.68 332.89 212.99 333.18 212.65 333.47 212.31 334.31 211.52 334.86 211.07 335.7 210.37 336.85 209.26 337.15 208.86 337.45 208.45 337.75 207.68 337.75 207.31 337.75 206.93 337.48 206.29 337.21 206.03 336.94 205.77 336.23 205.51 335.79 205.51 335.33 205.51 334.59 205.79 334.31 206.06 334.03 206.34 333.75 207.11 333.75 207.6 332.43 207.46 332.5 206.72 333.01 205.6 333.45 205.22 333.89 204.83 335.07 204.44 335.82 204.44 336.57 204.44 337.76 204.86 338.19 205.28 338.63 205.69 339.07 206.73 339.07 207.34 339.07 207.66 338.94 208.27 338.81 208.58 338.69 208.88 338.26 209.52 337.96 209.85 337.66 210.19 336.68 211.1 335.99 211.69 335.41 212.17 334.67 212.83 334.51 213 334.35 213.17 334.08 213.52 333.97 213.69 339.08 213.69Z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="black"/>
```

**Asterix***

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M362.54 649.67L363.2 647.65 364.33 648.05 365.97 648.73 366.48 649.03 366.35 647.74 366.21 645.97 366.2 645.49 368.27 645.49 368.25 646.19 368.08 647.95 367.94 649.01 368.67 648.64 370.36 647.96 371.31 647.65 371.96 649.67 371.06 649.96 369.28 650.36 368.41 650.46 368.84 650.84 370.07 652.19 370.86 653.15 369.15 654.36 368.74 653.8 367.76 652.27 367.2 651.3 366.67 652.31 365.74 653.84 365.35 654.36 363.67 653.15 364.49 652.14 365.67 650.79 366.03 650.46 365.11 650.28 363.37 649.89 362.54 649.67 362.54 649.67Z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="black"/>
```

Comment: Probably render -> OCR.

Comment: Do you realize that most captcha systems are based on what you are trying to do? A noisy SVG would make what you want impossible. With a clean SVG image your best bet would be an OCR.

Comment: It's a very clean diagram I've been sent which has been exported from AutoCAD. Seems like I just need to find a good OCR library.